# OpenCL context for Multiple Devices

Tags: c++, opencl

I've been starting out with OpenCL, and I've been wanting to create a `cl::Context` with multiple devices. While looking into the OpenCL 1.2 C++ Wrapper Api Specifications, I found this constructor for `cl::Context`:

> The constructor

```
cl::Context::Context(VECTOR_CLASS<Device>& devices, cl_context_properties * properties = NULL, void (CL_CALLBACK * pfn_notify)( const char * errorinfo, const void * private_info, ::size_t cb, void * user_data) = NULL, void * user_data = NULL, cl_int * err = NULL)
```

> creates an OpenCL context.
>
> *devices* is a pointer to a vector of unique devices returned by cl::Platform::getDevices. If more than one device is specified, a selection criteria may be applied to determine if the list of devices specified can be used together to create a context.
>
> ...

My questions are: What are the "criteria" applied by the OpenCL implementation? How should I guarantee that the list of devices I pass in are compatible? What devices are compatible (ie do they have to be the same device type or something?) And do they have to be from the same platform/vendor (it is kind of implied by "unique devices returned by cl::Platform::getDevices")?

The constructor would set the errcode to `CL_INVALID_DEVICE` if *devices* contains an invalid device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the "criteria" applied by the OpenCL implementation? How should I guarantee that the list of devices I pass in are compatible? What devices are compatible (ie do they have to be the same device type or something?)

The answers to all these questions are implementation-dependent. You have to guarantee that the list of devices is coming from a single Platform, but the implementation might apply some selection "criteria", if not all of the supported devices can work together within one context, which again is implementation-specific. You can use `cl::Context::getInfo` to see which devices are associated with the Context you created.

> And do they have to be from the same platform/vendor (it is kind of implied by "unique devices returned by cl::Platform::getDevices")?

The [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-cplusplus-1.2.pdf) states:

> `devices` is a pointer to a vector of unique devices returned by cl::Platform::getDevices

The vector here is returned from a specific platform, hence only one Platform can be used to create the context.

There is another constructor:

```
cl::Context::Context(cl_device_type type, ... )
```

> creates an OpenCL context from a device type that identifies the specific devices to use. The constructor
>   attempts to use the first platform that has a device of the specified type.

So also in this case, there is always a single Platform per Context. A platform basically is a specific OpenCL implementation by some vendor. In general, they do not interoperate with each other.